# Autofac - RouteConfig.cs - asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

thanks in advance for any help. I changed to mvc4 and start using app_start/routeconfig.cs to register routes.

Probably it dont have any relation with autofac but I cannot find a solution, does anyone know if its neccesary to declare `routetable.routes` in any additional place - I already declared `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` in global.asax - when planning to use autofac with mvc4 razor´s internet template?.

Currently no map.route definition is working in my app. I dont know if I have to declare an instance like

```
RegisterInstance(RouteTable.Routes);
```

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the minimum amount of code to configure Autofac for mvc. You will need to reference Autofac.Integration.Mvc, and if you're using webapi you need to reference Autofac.Integration.Webapi too.

```
public static class AutofacConfig
{
    public static IContainer Register()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly;
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(assembly);
        // If you don't need webapi, you can omit this, else you need Autofac.Integration.Webapi
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);

        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        // If you don't need webapi, you can omit this, else you need Autofac.Integration.Webapi
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

        return container;
    }
}
```

In Global.Asax you can then add

```
AutofacConfig.Register();
```

in the Application_Start method as one of the first calls.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but one question.. its not neccesary to include more information about routes? brgds!

Comment: No, autofac doesn't do anything with the routes itself. The issue will not probably be Autofac then. What do you have in your `RegisterRoutes` method?